# How to write a multiline SQL string in C# but treat it as a single line string

Tags: c#, sql

There is a part in the application where SQL statements are generated. There is a unit test for it that currently only compares if the given query string matches the expected query string. I'm using a multiline string with interpolation (simplified example)

```
command.Should().Be($@"UPDATE `todo`
                       SET `todo`.`is_done`=0
                       WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'");
```

Writing it this way the multiline string looks like this

```
"UPDATE `todo`
                                SET `todo`.`is_done`=0
                                WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'"
```

The identations are filled with empty characters. The generated SQL string by code is this

```
"UPDATE `todo` SET `todo`.`is_done`=0 WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'"
```

The unit test fails because the generated string does not match the expected string. How can I remove the empty characters from the expected string? Because currently the test fails with

> Expected string to be ... with a length of 377, but ... has a length
> of 206 ...

Comment: Perhaps think about changing your unit test? The test should pass if the query is correct, not necessarily if the SQL command text is identitcal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string concatenation to achieve a similar kind of formatting in source code, and the desired string value:

```
command.Should().Be("UPDATE `todo` " +
                    "SET `todo`.`is_done`=0 " +
                    "WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'");
```

Comment: Hm I thought this is ugly so I tried to use `$@` for this ...

Comment: @DevMail what’s ugly about it?

Comment: using the current approach I don't have to append a new line with `" + "` all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions :

1. you could not use @ and write it like

   `` command.Should().Be($"UPDATE `todo` SET `todo`.`is_done`=0 WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'"); ``
2. you could use string concatenation like in the another answer

   `` command.Should().Be("UPDATE `todo` " + "SET `todo`.`is_done`=0 " + "WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'"); ``
3. you could normallize strings to remove all spaces and \n , e.g. with regex

   `Regex.Replace(s1, @"\s", "");`

but you need to do it for both lines

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two options:

## Don't use newlines

Just initialize your string without newlines and use string concatenation:

```
expectedCommand = "UPDATE `todo` " +
                  "SET `todo`.`is_done`=0 " +
                  "WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'";

command.Should().Be(expectedCommand);
```

## Strip whitespaces

If you really need to input with whitespaces, you can remove all whitespaces from the actual string and the expected string with a Regex before comparing them:

```
expectedCommand = $@"UPDATE `todo`
                   SET `todo`.`is_done`=0
                   WHERE `todo`.`id`='a9cebb04-fa7d-4071-9f3e-0704bd3352fa'";

actualCommandTrimmed = Regex.Replace(command, @"\s+", "");
expectedCommandTrimmed = Regex.Replace(expectedCommand, @"\s+", "");

actualCommandTrimmed.Should().Be(expectedCommandTrimmed);
```

But as @RobertSynoradzki mentioned you shouldn't do this:

> Regex is not very performant. When you hardcode something only to run intensive operations on it just after (in this example: regex), you could always hardcode the result instead.

Comment: While technically doable, the first suggestion teaches bad habits - you shouldn't have to regex a string you've just input just to clean whitespaces you've just made. The second suggestion is fine, but why the unnecessary `$@` before each string?

Comment: @RobertSynoradzki you're correct. I updated my answer. Maybe you can add some more infos about why it is bad habit.

Comment: Regex is not very performant. When you *hardcode* something only to run intensive operations on it just after (in this example: regex), you could always *hardcode the result* instead.